# how to set setLanguageHints

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

// Base64 encode the **`JPEG`**

```
base64EncodedImage.encodeContent(imageBytes);
annotateImageRequest.setImage(base64EncodedImage);

                    // add the features we want
                    annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(new ArrayList<Feature>() {{
                        Feature textDetection = new Feature();
                        textDetection.setType("TEXT_DETECTION");
                        add(textDetection);
                    }});
                    ImageContext ImageCon = new ImageContext();
                    ImageCon.cou("th,us");
                    annotateImageRequest.setImageContext(ImageCon);
                    // Add the list of one thing} to the request
                    add(annotateImageRequest);
                }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example on how to add language hints to `ImageContext` should be:

```
ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext();
String [] languages = { "zh-TW" };
imageContext.setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList(languages));
```

Answer (score 0):

The ImageContext class has changed to a builder pattern

```
ImageContext.newBuilder().addLanguageHints("en")
```